# State the range of the function below.

Tags: functions, relations

Sketch the graph of $f:x \mapsto -4x + 5$  , $x<2$ and state the range.

I got the graph, but can't state the range...how to find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=-4x+5$ is simply a straight line. At $x=2$, you have $f(x)=-3$; moreover, as $x\rightarrow -\infty$ it holds that $f(x)\rightarrow +\infty$. So the range of $f$ is simply the open interval $(-3,+\infty)$.

Comment: I get $f(x)$ is greater or equal to $-3$...is this right?

Comment: Well, you said that $x<2$ so it never attains $y=-3$. In other words, $-3$ is not included in the range of $f$ - the range is $(-3,\infty)$.